# Layouting a small table with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

I'm very novice to HTML and CSS and have not yet "gotten it" how it all works.
I am trying to achieve a table made of two rows, in which the first row only has one column and spans over the two columns of the second row.

In the first row I have an input box and I'd like the row to conform to the height of this input box. On the bottom left I have a button with its own style and I'd like the row (and cell) to conform to the size of the button. On the bottom right I have an image and I'd like the image to scale (preserving its aspect ratio) such that it either fills the height of the row (and floats to the right) or the width of the cell and centers vertically.

The table will fill its container (a div) horizontally.

Can anyone give me hints?

I don't necessarily need a table element, just something that achieves the effect without me having to specify pixel sizes to keep everything scalable.

Here is what I have now (some garbage may still be in there...):

```css
table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}

input {
  font-size: 16px;
}

input[name="text"] {
  line-height:1.875;
  display:table-cell;
  width:100%;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #d7b221;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 1.4em 1.6em 1.2em;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: 52px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input name="text" placeholder="Enter some text here"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Click Here"/></td>
<td><a href="x"><img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/car.svg"/></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I guess it ultimately boils down to this:

```
#container {
  border:1px solid red;
}

#main_img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

#dep_img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

<div id="container">
    <img id="main_img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg">
    <img id="dep_img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg">
</div>
```

Is there any way in which the size (height) of the main image can dictate the size (height) of the dep image?

Comment: Bootstrap! http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Please post the code you have so far so we can take a look.

Comment: With regard to the sizes, that's easy: don't specify any. By default, block elements become the same sizes as the heights of their contents, so that's taken care of.

Comment: I've added some concept code

Comment: You shouldn't put anything except `<th>` or `<td>` inside a `<tr>`. Not even if you give it a style of `display:table-cell`; that's not how it works.

Comment: Sorry for that. I fixed the table.

Comment: Is the only issue here that the image doesn't fill the row? It seems the other goals are already met: each row being the height of the `input` within it.

Comment: Well it's the scaling of the image within it's cell... either fill width or fill height, whichever comes first by keeping the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a table to layout in the first place when you can do all that with just CSS. 
Learn CSS from this site: http://learnlayout.com/

Comment: I'll give it read. Thanks. I'm not that fluent with CSS and although I know it can do a lot I miss the experience. I'm just trying to do a couple of things with what I know.

Comment: Does that site have an alternative to `colspan` that can be used on non-tables?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question :)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is that all images are of the same size then that can be easily addressed by using a class for the images.

```css
#container {
  border:1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.my-kind-of-image {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img class="my-kind-of-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg">
    <img class="my-kind-of-image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkF9Q.jpg">
    <img class="my-kind-of-image" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/car.svg"/>
</div>
```